# Grammatical function of "for you" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

> The best thing would be **for you** to tell her.

Could you please help me identify the grammatical function of "for you"?

Comment: "For" is a subordinator, introducing the non-finite clause "you to tell her".

Answer (score 1):

**For you** doesn't have a grammatical function on its own. It's part of **for you to tell her**, which is a *infinitive clause*: a clause that functions as a noun phrase. In particular, it's a *for-infinitive*, which has a subject: *for* [subject] *to* [verb]. These clauses can include more than just a verb, for example: "*For the motor to spontaneously catch fire and burn the house down* is impossible."

It's possible to say the same thing without an infinitive, by using a gerund clause instead: "The best thing would be **you telling her**." But infinitives are more likely for hypothetical future actions, so a native speaker would be more likely to say "for you to tell her".